# Plant identification

Tags: botany, species-identification

What plant species is this?

Its stalk looks like a grapevine, but the leaves & flowers not. It bloomed this week (Mid-June). I have found it in Turkey, Amasya.
[image: flower]

If you want, I can add more shots of plant.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE and thanks for your question. I edited the question wording a bit to improve clarity. I substituted "body" for "stalk" (the part you are holding), I hope that fits your description. I also rotated the picture. Feel free to roll back my edits, they are just suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a kind of honeysuckle. The picture below is for Japanese honeysuckle (Lonicera japonica), but your specimen is different in the way the flowers are arranged and that the distal-most paired leaves are clasping the stem.

[image]

It might be Lionicera periclymenum, or Lonicera etrusca (there are about 150 species of honeysuckle); [L. etrusca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonicera_etrusca) is pictured below (the color is irrelevant) which is native to Europe.

[image]